# (wsl) packages want to downgrade for some reason when I think the latest should be compatible though not found; blocked new installs for some packages

Tags: apt, package-management, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am working in ubuntu through wsl today and having a problem.

My issue is that when trying to install multiple packages I have received an error similar to the one below:

[image: package install error libuv1-dev]

This wasn't the top level package I was trying to install. In the pictured case was trying to install npm I get an error about node-gyp, which said it needed libnode-dev, which needs libuv1-dev so I followed the dep chain to the problem package.

Additionally this occurred with libssl-dev which popped up when trying to install a python verion with pyenv. I don't have a screenshot but it looked very similar, except it ended with "ubuntu2.13". So, it seems like apt maybe isn't getting the latest packages? Maybe something else going on? I'm not very sharp with troubleshooting this.

Running apt update seems to succeed without error which I ran several times while feeling confused. Let me know what yall think - my sources.list is the original from wsl focal 20.04 (I downloaded a fresh tar and refreshed it just in case).

I also sanity checked some random top level package (httpie) that installed fine through apt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) FYI: apt update only updates the list of available software. It doesn't make any changes to your packages. You need to run `sudo apt upgrade` to bring your packages up-to-date. Your system should be up-to-date before you attempt to install new software

Comment: No, but thank you. I have run upgrade (with no packages needing updates) as well as `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` with no results there either.